# Cypress and Vaadin app will fire a error popup that prevent test to works

Tags: vaadin, cypress, vaadin8

I need to test a Vaadin app, and sometimes, a popup is displayed about a communication problem.

This seems to be a Cypress error report, be it is displayed with the Vaadin template, so it is a bit confusing to find witch part is creating the popup (as the 'Take not of any unsaved data.....' is a vaadin typical message).

Once this popup is displayed, we can't run any tests again.

I have never seen this popup before, only when we are using Cypress.
I know that Cypress will act as a MITM to be able to mock server replies, but in my case I don't need this mechanism, is it possible to configure Cypress to not try to override this communication so that this popup will not be displayed ?

Or is there something to change to make it works ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of Cypress seems to have solved this problem.